# Konva.js, what measurement unit are they using?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, canvas, konvajs

I'm currently using Konva.js within my Vue.js application.
I'm wondering, what measurement unit are they using in Konva.js?
I got an array of objects, when I increase the y-value by 20 it's just moving a tiny bit.

Comment: With scale set to 1, the units are screen pixels, so adding 20 to y would move your shape 20px to the right.

Answer (score 1):

`Konva` is using CSS pixels for measurement.